# PGStac stac-fastapi Does not return number matched SEARCH API

Tags: python, search, request, response, geojson

I ran stacfast-api and pgstac in a docker.
I loaded test collections by running the following commands:

```
pypgstac load collections ../pgstac/tests/testdata/collections.ndjson 
pypgstac load items ../pgstac/tests/testdata/items.ndjson
```

when I search by setting limit = 2 only.
Why it doesn’t return matched in the context data structure?

EXAMPLE

```
POST  
http://127.0.0.1:8080/search/
{
    "limit": 2
}
```

RESPONSE FOR TEST EXAMPLE DATA:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "context": {
        "limit": 2,
        "returned": 2
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "pgstac-test-item-0003",
            "bbox": [
                -85.379245,
                30.933949,
                -85.308201,
                31.003555
            ],
     
        ......................
```

Thanks for any answers